# Telling Mongoose which database to use - in a node.js Express application

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have an Node.js Express web app running.

I have two database connections, the system_db is created with "Mongoose.connect", the user_db is created with "Mongoose.createConnection". This seems to make them separate and have different connection pools. Although this could be the crux of the problem.

I have code dealing with with a Mongoose model

in the model file I have:

```
var authSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    teamName: String,
    league: String,
    players: []

});


var Team = module.exports = mongoose.model('teams',authSchema);
```

in my main file I have two connections:

one is a system database

```
connection_uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
system_db = mongoose.connect(connection_uri.concat("sparks"), {
    native_parser : true
}, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

the other is a user database

```
 user_db = mongoose.createConnection(connection_uri.concat(user_id));
```

then I have this piece of code in my main file which finds a Team object based off id:

```
app.param('team_id', function(req, res, next, team_id) {

    Team.findOne(team_id, function(err, team) {

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!team) {
            throw new Error("no team matched");
        }
        req.team = team;
        next();
    });
});
```

the problem is that the app.param function above is not finding any matches for teams, even though they exist in a collection in the user_db database. this means, that I am thinking my model is pointing to the wrong database somehow? Somehow it must be pointing to this system_db instead of the user_db. Could this be right? How would I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below method opens a connection to the `system_db` and is binded to the `mongoose` object,.i.e the current mongoose object is modified. The return type is **not** a `Connection`.

```
system_db = mongoose.connect(connection_uri.concat("sparks")...
```

Now when you again do:

```
user_db = mongoose.createConnection(connection_uri.concat(user_id));
```

This creates a **new** Connection to the `user` database and returns a **connection**, but does not modify the `mongoose` instance. The mongoose instance is still binded to the `system_db` database connection.

Since Team model is obtained from the same mongoose instance,

```
var Team = mongoose.model('teams',authSchema);
```

whatever operation is done on this `model` effectively occurs in the `connection` that the mongoose instance holds, and that is of the `system_db` database.

So you need to obtain the model from the `user_db` connection :

```
var user_db = mongoose.createConnection(..);
// retrieve the Team model
var Team= user_db.model('teams'); // not from mongoose instance.
```

use `createConnection` wherever you want to obtain a connection.

Comment: hmmm, thanks, this is discouraging. I want to be able to load that file (with Team defined in it) before the user_db variable is defined...

Comment: furthermore, if the user logs out, and logs in as a different user, the user_db variable would be redefined.

Comment: in an ideal universe, I could pass the save method the database variable, so it would be var team = new Team({}); team.save(user_db); you know what I am sayin'?

Comment: Why are you maintaining a different database for each user? You should  make your database queries `specific` to the user rather than maintaining a database for each user. That way the Model Team will be common to all the users.

Comment: each users collections might be very large so it is better to have them in separate databases I believe

Comment: turns out having each user in a different DB is a bad idea